# Evalute part of LINQ expression before translating to SQL statements

Tags: vb.net, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

```
Dim instanceOfMyClass As New MyClass()
'... Some code to manipulate instanceOfMyClass.MyArrayField
Dim thisYear = DateTime.Today.Year
Dim records = (
  From i In dbContext.MyTable
  Where i.MyCol >= thisYear - instanceOfMyClass.MyArrayField.Length AndAlso i.MyCol <= thisYear - 1
).ToArray()

Class MyClass
  Friend MyArrayField As String()
End Class
```

Running above code throws an exception because EF6 doesn't know how to translate `instanceOfMyClass.MyArrayField.Length` to SQL expression. Of course I can do:

```
Dim anIntermediateVar = instanceOfMyClass.MyArrayField.Length
Dim records = (
  From i In dbContext.MyTable
  Where i.MyCol >= thisYear - anIntermediateVar AndAlso i.MyCol <= thisYear - 1
).ToArray()
```

It just feels a bit unintuitive to me. I wonder if there's a syntax/function/whatever to mark a section of expression so that .NET runtime will evaluate the code within before translating? Something like:

```
From i In dbContext.MyTable
Where i.MyCol >= thisYear - EvalThisFirst(instanceOfMyClass.MyArrayField.Length) AndAlso i.MyCol <= thisYear - 1
```

so that when EF6 doing LINQ-to-TSQL translation it's translating from:

```
From i In dbContext.MyTable
Where i.MyCol >= thisYear - 5 AndAlso i.MyCol <= thisYear - 1
```

Does such mechanism exist?

Comment: Is what you suggest really any more intuitive? You still have to know what parts can be mapped to SQL and which can't and handle them explicitly in your code. What you're suggesting would require some additional modification of the language syntax because it couldn't merely be a method called at run time because that would not solve anything. I'm not aware of anything that matches that description and I'm very confident that no such thing exists because I'd be shocked if they'd make such a significant change to the language for such an insignificant benefit.

Comment: You could write an `Expression` tree modifier to add evaluation of more complicated constant expressions to the query (e.g. `(from i ...).EvalExpressions().ToArray()` but I doubt if it is worth it. Note that newer EF such as EF Core 6 can translate it fine.